# Check if cordova-plugin-splashscreen is visible?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, splash-screen

Using the cordova-plugin-splashscreen is there a way to check if the splashscreen is visible or hidden?

I know you can hide and show it with:

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

But can I check the status on device ready, i.e, something like this?

```
If(splashscreen == visible){    
   Do Something;    
}else{    
   Do Something Different;    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Show` and `hide` are the only 2 functions available, so no.
But since you can choose to show at start or not, then you can track this status yourself when calling `show` or `hide`.